# How to restore persistent disk in kubernetes statefulset?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a gcePersistentDisk with an elasticsearch index. When I delete and recreate the statefulset, I want to reuse this disk so the same index is available on the new statefulset.

I've managed to rebind the disk, `my-es-disk`, to a new statefulset, but when I connect to the container and check for the index, there are no indices.

I've reviewed Google and k8s docs, and it seems like the yamls are correct, but I still cannot retain the index. I am sure it's something simple! Thanks for your help!

My workflow:

1 - Create storage class

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ssd
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
  zone: us-central1-a
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

2 - Create PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-es
spec:
  storageClassName: ssd
  capacity:
    storage: 3G
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: my-es-disk
    fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim-es
spec:
  storageClassName: ssd
  volumeName: pv-es
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3G
```

3 - Deploy statefulSet

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elastic-data
  labels:
    app: elastic-data
    area: devs
    role: nosql
    version: "6.1.4"
    environment: elastic
spec:
  serviceName: elastic-data
  replicas: 1
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elastic-data
        area: devs
        role: nosql
        version: "6.1.4"
        environment: elastic
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - name: elastic-data
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.4
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "512Mi"
          limits:
            memory: "1024Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data-volume
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      volumes:
      - name: data-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pv-claim-es
```

Comment: What do you see when you ls the /usr/share/elasticsearch/data directory in the elasticsearch container?

Comment: @ericstaples I see two folders, `lost+found` and `nodes`. Is that correct?

Comment: And is the contents of the `nodes` directory both non-empty and owned by the `elasticsearch` user? Further, what _is_ in the `nodes` directory?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel `nodes` is owned by `elasticsearch` and has a subdirectory called `0`

Comment: Anything interesting in the logs? And I presume you've double checked that `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` is in fact the data path for that Pod's configuration?

Comment: Yes, the path is correct. I've seen `recovered [0] indices into cluster_state` in the logs immediately after it starts but it looks like everything mounts correctly

Comment: Your config files all look good so data should not be reclaimed as long as you are using the same PVC each time. Before deleting a statefulSet, are you able to find the index at /usr/share/elasticsearch/data? Just to make sure the data is there before you remove the statefulSets.